# Seperate between words in Sql server full text search

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search, sql-server-2012

I use sql server 2012 and have full text search on Description field of Document table.

I can't find numbers that stick to alphabet characters with following query:

```
select * 
from document
where contains (Description,'"123"')
```

how can I separate between numbers and alphabets on.

some of numbers should not separated such as date 2014/01/01

I have Persian description.

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you looking for strings that contain the numbers 123?

Comment: @Caspian. Yes. but 123abc not found in my search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Word breakers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142509.aspx) are the most effective way to handle this scenario. They define where the word boundaries exist when text is being indexed. (Example: the default word-breaker indexes "the dog-catcher" as `[the] [dog] [catcher]`). You can create a custom word breaker to split digits and letters (example: "123abc" becomes `[123] [abc]`). This will enable a search for "123" to match "123abc".

Unfortunately I don't have an example to show. I recommend you start with the link above and also look at the Windows Search SDK docs starting with the links below. (MSSQL and Windows Search both use the same technology.)

[Windows Search Developer's Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee872109%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

[Windows Search: Extending the Index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb318649%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the NEAR search?

```
    select * 
    from document
    where contains (Description,'123 NEAR abc')
```

Comment: I want to search only 123. I don't want search 123 near abc. when I search for 123, description with 123abc not found in my search.

Comment: Ah, sorry. What about '123*'

Comment: Thanks. I want to search full match words. by '123*', you found 1234 and 1235 etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have sql 2012. But did you try the search '123[a-z]'
I know it works in the basic searches: WHERE Description LIKE '%123[a-z]%'

Comment: Thanks Please see this Link (can't use '123[a-z]' for full text search): http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx

Comment: Oh well, sorry I couldn't help.
After reading the documentation, I couldn't find a better answer than the standard search. Hope someone else can help. :)